# How do I run a program on Windows 10 startup that can't be closed?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to run a program on startup instead of Windows Explorer and have this program remain open so it can't be closed. Is there a way to achieve this? The program is for employees to sign in when they come to work. Presently they close the program and say it wasn't working, I'm trying to find a way for it to remain open. It would be helpful if it was the only program that could be run under this restricted login. This PC is not joined to a domain. Thanks

Comment: There is no way to implement any of the solutions to prevent an application from being closed if you cannot enforce domain policies, for instance, to disable Task Manager. Additionally, the program itself, would have to have no exit mechanic or close button.  This sounds like a people problem not a software problem

Comment: @Ramhound not entirely true.

Comment: Given you want to run the program instead of Windows Explorer, you want to adjust the shell. By doing so, when you start the computer, instead of a taskbar being shown, this program is shown. It is impossible to prevent this from being closed unless you disable task manager and such through group policy, but if you close the program, then you have an empty desktop anyway, so that is probably as good.

Comment: I suppose Kiosk Mode would work.  I just assumed the application wasn't going to be compatible. What could be done is a scheduled task that continuously verifies the application is open.  A combination of killing explorer and maximizing the desired application (disabling the ability to minimize the applicatioN) would get you close to your goals.  Of course ALT+F4 will just close the applicaiton.

Comment: A Windows Service can check if it's been closed, and then restart itself. However, messing with Windows Explorer is *not* recommended; just have the sign-in app appear on the desktop.

Comment: Have you tried using the NoClose app? It removes the X in the upper right corner of the program window of your choice so it cannot be closed.